Extract an access token from a Post request and use it in another post request in Postman
I have a Postman collection that consists of 15 post requests. One of my requests is a POST request that generate an access token which expires in 3 minutes and it's response looks like this:
"access_token": "accessTokenValue",
"expires_in": 300

After running this I need all the other requests to extract the access token from this response body and use it to send those requests.
I have used following code to retrieve the access_token from the first request:
pm.test("response is ok",  ()=>{
if( pm.response.to.have.status(200)){
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("access_token", jsonData.access_token);}})

Now, what I want to do is add the access token I retrieved from here and add to the other request. I have gone through  following documents,
https://blog.postman.com/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/
https://community.postman.com/t/how-to-extract-post-request-field-values-in-other-get-tests/17391
and few more and failed to understand how this works.
What did I miss in this process?

Consider using OAuth2 auto-login for Postman

You've already extracted the token here.
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("access_token", jsonData.access_token);}})

What you haven't mentioned is how the other requests need to use the token.
I suspect it needs to be set as a Bearer Token in the header for the subsequent requests which can be done using the Authorization helpers.

This can be added on the individual requests, or at the folder\collection level if it affects more than one request.
You can also use the Authorization helper to create the token.


This solution worked. However, this token get expired every 3 minutes. So, my requirement is to run access token before every scripts runs, which means I'm guessing I can add a Pre-request Script to run generate access token script before run it and then inject the new token to the request before it runs. Do you have any idea how this works?

Doesn't the auto refresh token work?  If not, I can edit my answer to include a pre-request script that you can take as a baseline.  The example is authenticating to Microsoft, so you might have to tweak it slightly if using another authorization service.  (With particular attention to the date format, as I they always seem to be slightly different).

I use this script on the tests tab
`var res = pm.response.json()
pm.environment.set('AUTH_TOKEN',res['token'])
console.log(res['token'])

pm.test("Status code is 200", () => {
  pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});`

now add the variable 'AUTH_TOKEN' to the variables folder and add the token on other requests to use 'AUTH_TOKEN' variable.
